# Multiple introductory word elements and commas

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am struggling with the punctuation of sentences with multiple introductory elements. Example 1:

> However, at the current development stage, this feature is not implemented.

Example 2:

> However, in one way or another, both of you are correct.

According to [1](https://content.nroc.org/DevelopmentalEnglish/unit04/Foundations/commas-with-introductory-phrases.html) ("If there are two or more phrases and/or clauses before the subject, only put a comma after the last one") and [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/2yifej/what_is_this_a_secondary_introductory_phrase_and), the first comma needs to be removed. However, I have a bad stomach feeling about that. Nonetheless, I am not a native speaker. Is there a general rule how to proceed in these cases?

Edit: I already read post [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476791/how-to-punctuate-a-sentence-containing-two-introductory-phrases-or-words). However, I thought there was a more precise rule. Apart from that, I don't trust the accepted answer because it has a negative score.

Comment: In principle, the "rules of construction" for English allow ***any number*** of consecutive (adverbial) introductory elements before the "primary" clause. So we can extend your own text to ***Nonetheless, as you can see, obviously** I am not a native speaker.* The actual orthography best suited to the text very much depends on the *specific* text, but there are no hard-and-fast rules. Personally, I'd probably set off ***—as you can see—*** with em-dashes rather than commas in my example, but opinions may differ on that one.

Comment: Standalone _however_, _nevertheless_, _furthermore_ etc always require a comma.

Comment: @FF You use em-dashes in running text? _To think_ I stopped using 'spelt' for 'spelled', was it, when the 'authorities' say it's still OK in the UK.

Comment: fev: I already read that post. However, I thought there was a more precise rule. Apart from that, I didn't trust the accepted answer with negative score.
@FumbleFingers Thanks, that does agree well with the usual english texts I read. Is there some rules one can cite if you have an argument with somebody about this specific punctuation?

Comment: However, this feature is not implemented at the current stage of development. Ta dah: One comma! (I'm being somewhat facetious!) Don

Comment: The second commas are not mandatory, but I'd retain them.